# Modify a binary matrix to minimize the sum of values of the rows

Tags: algorithms, np-hard

I have a matrix of zeros and ones, i.e., $\mathbf{X}=[x_{ij}]$ with $x_{ij}\in\{0,1\}$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,m$ and $j=1,2,\ldots,n$. Associated with each row  $i$ of the matrix $\mathbf{X}$ a set of the consecutive number of zeros $S_i$. Row $i$ has a value $v_i=\sum_{k\in S_i}\lfloor k/2\rfloor$.

I would like to modify this matrix such that:

- $\sum_{i=1}^mx_{ij}\leq1$ for all $j=1,2,\ldots,n$: keep only a single one in each column; and
- $\sum_{i=1}^mv_i$ is as small as possible.

An example.

Let $$\mathbf{X}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&1&0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix}.$$ Here, we have

- $S_1=\{1, 3\}$ and $v_1=1$;
- $S_2=\{6\}$ and $v_2=3$;
- $S_3=\{2, 1, 2\}$ and $v_3=2$; and
- $S_4=\{2, 2\}$ and $v_4=2$.

If I make the following modification to $\mathbf{X}$:

- $x_{21}=x_{41}=0$;
- $x_{13}=0$;
- $x_{47}=0$;
  I would get the following modified matrix $$\mathbf{X}'=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0\\\end{pmatrix}.$$

We have satisfied the the first constraint of $\sum_{i=1}^mx_{ij}\leq1$ for all $j=1,2,\ldots,n$. Now, we have

- $S_1=\{5\}$ and $v_1=2$;
- $S_2=\{7\}$ and $v_2=3$;
- $S_3=\{2, 1, 2\}$ and $v_3=2$; and
- $S_4=\{3, 3\}$ and $v_4=2$.

The value of $\sum_{i=1}^mv_i$ if $9$. If I try all possible combinations of the modifications I end up with the one that gives the best value of $\sum_{i=1}^mv_i$.

Can we solve this problem in polytime?

Comment: Just a comment: if we didn't have the floor, it would be trivial, as then we would have $v_i=\sum_{k\in S_i} k/2 = (\text{number of zeroes})/2$. Then all you'd have to do is arbitrarily remove 1s in the matrix until there were at most one per column. So the whole potential difficulty of this problem (I didn't give it much thought) must lie in the $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$. Essentially you prefer odd intervals of 0s than even ones.